# Generalization of the sign representation to Hopf algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, hopf-algebras

For $G$ a finite group, the sign representation is the one-dimensional representation $\pi : G \to \mathbb{C}$ with $\pi(g)$ the sign of the permutation given by the action of $g$ on $G$ by left multiplication.

*Question*: how to generalize the sign representation to semisimple finite dimensional Hopf algebras?

Comment: If the Hopf algebra is cocommutative, then there is Larson's character (see Section 7.1 of Sweedler's "Hopf algebras" book). Not sure about the general situation.

Comment: This definition of the sign representation doesn't give what I would expect to be the desired answer for $S_n$, when $n \geq 4$. Specifically, the sign of the permutation of $g \cdot$ on $S_n$ is always $1$ for $n \geq 4$ and any $g \in S_n$. Is that what you wanted your definition to do?

Comment: I might be confused but isn't the representation defined in the OP just the determinant of the regular representation? I think that this can be generalized to all cocommutative finite-dimensional Hopf algebras

Comment: @DenisNardin In the group case the determinant is $\pm 1$. This is not going to carry over in general. It would be helpful if to see a list of properties that one might want to see in such a sign representation (besides giving the sign rep. in the group case).

Comment: @DenisNardin: why do you need to assume cocommutativity?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Because I think it is needed to pass the module structure on $V^{\otimes r} $ to the quotient $\Lambda^r V $. I haven't checked all details but you need something in order to behave well with respect to the $S_r $ action

Comment: It seems that the only groups in which this representation will not be trivial are groups $G$ in which the 2-Sylow subgroup is cyclic, isn't it? In any case, a general finite dimensional semisimple Hopf algebra will not necessarily have a 1-dimensional nontrivial representation, and we cannot talk about determinants in representations of a noncocommutative Hopf algebra.